# How to disable pasting in Matlab's edit field?

Tags: matlab

is there a way to disable pasting (control + v) in a Matlab edit field which is in a GUI that I am developing?

Example:

```
mainFig = figure;
% is it possible to disable paste (control + v) is this edit field?
editField = uicontrol('Parent', mainFig,...
                      'Style', 'Edit',...
                      'Units', 'Normalized',...
                      'Position', [0.3, 0.05, 0.15, 0.05],...
                      'Tag', 'simpleEditField');

uicontrol('Parent', mainFig, 'Style', 'Text',...
                      'Units', 'Normalized',... 
                      'Position', [0.1, 0.05, 0.15, 0.05],...
                      'String', 'Enter your ID:');
```

Thanks in advance,

Rhenan

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @excaza: given that there has been an example now, how is this still off-topic?

Comment: @excaza: I didn't mean to single you out specifically. Apologies.

Comment: @Jonas sorry, that was way too aggressive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `KeyPressFcn` property of your edit field, so that it acts appropriately when receiving ctrl+V as input (note: not all operating systems use ctrl+V for pasting). Basically, you want to throw away whatever input pasting would provide.

See e.g. the user-submitted function [`logindialog`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8499-login/content/logindlg.m) on the File Exchange for an example.